# How to get even gradient repetition using modulo?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to apply the modulo on a gradient to get some repetition, but the problem is that the result is different from one gradient to another because of random inputs to the modulo, as you can see here:
[image]

I want the gradient to repeat itself equally, not like this. Is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: Could you post your full node setup?

Comment: @miceterminator The full node tree is too big,and it has nothing to do with the image I showed,I edited the question to include only important nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really simple. What you need is to, *first*, modulo the gradient texture by a value that is less than one and then divide by that same value:

[image]

The problem you're experiencing is due to the image's resolution. The only way to fix this is to render to a higher resolution image.

Here's the .blend:

[image]

Comment: I edited the question,this wont fix the problem.

Comment: o.O Did you try my .blend?

Comment: I did,It has the same problem.decrease the value input and you will see it.

Comment: @OmarAhmad That's due to your resolution.

Comment: It is not actually,the modulo will apply for random values due to working with floating values .thats why this happen.